# Game theory, Book by Tirole and Fudenberg, Never a weak best response,unclear example

Tags: examples-counterexamples, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

In [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads146/ebook/635671/MIT%20Press%20-%20Game%20Theory--Fudenberg%20&%20Tirole--579p.pdf) book,
I have the following problem:
on page 446, there is a sentence:
Note that $(0.9,0.9)$ is not removed by NWBR, as D is not dominated after C is deleted.

I do not understand this "as". Why this condition implies that $(0.9,0.9)$ is *not* deleted?Can someone kindly go through the definition of Never a weak best response and help me? I also used the definition on page 193 [here](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~dirkb/teach/pdf/cho/1987%20signalling.pdf) which might be more clear then that in the book.

Comment: This is not an answer: I think there is a typo in Fudenberg and Tirole. In page 446, it should read: "Once E is pruned, **C** is weakly dominated" (by M) "and (2,2) is not a stable payoff". The version of the textbook you mention says that **D** is weakly dominated, but I believe this is a typo/error.

Comment: The problem is not the definition of a NWBR but rather the concept of being NWBR *within* an equilibrium component...